# weighing of probabilities in a multi horizon framework

Tags: bayesian-network, time-complexity

I shall start with an example so it's clear what I'd like to explore:

I have to decide how many sigarettes to smoke in a day.

1. One person tells me they will me kill should it rain. his credibility
   is `alfa`.
2. Another person tells me they will kill
       should it snow. his credibility is `beta`.
3. Another person tells me they will kill should it thunder. his credibility is
           `gamma`.

all the other people whose opinions I have not collected may think in any number of ways which may partially, completely or not at all think like the people lsited above. their collective credibility is `epsilon`.

I have historical data on when it rained, it snowed or when and how requently thunders went down (and what happened to the people to smoked a certain amount of cigarettes on different timeframes) but how do I assign the probabilities which would lead me to the amount of optimal sigarettes I'd need to smoke today?

like `omega1 * alfa + omega2 * beta + omega3 * gamma + (1-omega1-omega2-omega3) * epsilon` . which gives me a weighted credibility. I multiply thsi value by a factor and I obtain the sigarettes to smoke (no utility theory, just optimization). the problems lie within the facts that:

1. the events are triggered: they are not deterministic in time
2. how to standardize the different time frames?

in order to solve this nightmarish problem, what should I look at in terms of books / topics / and so on?

I realize the question might sound vague but I wanted to receive as much guidance as possible (hoping not to trespass the precision boundaries of the usual question asked here)

**p.s.:** some background and hyphotesis: all individuals are equal, each person credibility is not to be inferred.

Comment: Anyone? Is the question unclear ?

Comment: gonna bump it out of despair